# Check for featured image in WP_Query

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-query, post-thumbnails

Is there a way to filter posts by featured image when initialising a WP_Query object?

Example

```
$my_query = WP_Query(array("has_thumbnail"=>true));
```

or, more ideally

```
$my_query = WP_Query(array("has_thumbnail_size"=>"custom_size"));
```

Answer (score 9):

Technically featured image is custom field with name `_thumbnail_id` that holds attachment ID. So you can easily query with something like:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Size on other hand is attribute of that attachment and not post itself. You will need to loop through attachment and get sizes they have (if I remember right it should be in data returned by [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach of filtering the posts *after* the query using whether the `wp_get_attachment_thumb_url()` returns an empty string to determine if the post has a thumbnail (featured image).

```
//get all the posts however your query does it. simple example when there aren't a lot: 
$args = array("nopaging" => true);
$posts = (new WP_Query($args))->posts;

//filter the posts array by looking up the thumb_url and seeing if it's empty
$posts_without_thumbnails = array_filter($posts,  function($post){
  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
  return ( wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $post_thumbnail_id ) == "");
} );
```

If you need this to happen during the query, you can probably make a wordpress filter or action out of it or intercept the [query_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).