# Find posts without featured image?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, featured-post

I need way to find post(s) without featured image set.
I use WP as gallery site and for every post I set featured image. I wish to check if there is any post(s) without featured image.

Any code to paste on same custom page template to list post(s) (if any) without featured image?

Comment: Check the answer to this similar question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25726/check-for-featured-image-in-wp-query

Answer (score 6):

You can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-featured-images/

In description it says "You can also see posts with no featured image at a glance."

But from code side, wordpress manages images, documents any media by creating an attachment post for holding the information about that media and it's relation (if any) with other post/posts, which means you need sql query to find all posts without any images attached. To retrieve all posts without any image attached you can execute a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID), p.post_title, p.post_content FROM `wp_posts` p
LEFT JOIN wp_posts im ON p.ID = im.post_parent AND im.post_type = "attachment" 
WHERE p.post_status ='publish' 
AND p.post_type = "post" 
AND im.ID IS NULL
AND p.post_content NOT REGEXP 'src=".*"'
```

last code will remove posts which includes images inside it.